# Evaluating expression in SQL with XQuery (without stored procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery-sql

I am trying to evaluate an expression in a function, and it happens that XQuery is not able to get string from the SQL variable

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML = ''
DECLARE @Formula AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1+1'
SELECT @XML.query(@Formula)
```

Using ...

```
SELECT @XML.query('sql:variable("@Formula")')
```

... just returns a string `1+1`, and not the sum.

Is there a way to make this work in SQL (without using stored procedures, because those will not run form within the function)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way to evaluate expressions in TSQL is using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`, but neither of those can be used within a user-defined function (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850894/string-expression-to-be-evaluated-to-number)). You mentioned using a function, but it isn't clear if it's a TSQL UDF or not; if you can be more precise about how you're executing this code then someone may have a better answer.

Comment: @Podnlife Thank you for your answer. So, I guess either this should be a 1) CLR library, or 2) stored procedure, or 3) return a string and finish calculation in the application (in my case it is possible). No way to do this in the UDF. And yeah, it _is_ a T-SQL UDF :)

Comment: Yes, those are exactly your options. A TSQL UDF [cannot modify the database state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx), which makes sense because most people would not want a query like `select dbo.MyFunc(SomeColumn) from dbo.SomeTable` to also modify data.