# SQL Server calculate string value

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @table table
(
    Col1 varchar(50),
    Col2 varchar(50)
)

insert into @table
    select '100', '*10+2'

select Col1 + '' + Col2 
from @table
```

Expected output is: 1002

Can you please help?

Comment: Have you written any kind of parser for this?
Also, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850894/string-expression-to-be-evaluated-to-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
Declare @table table
(
Col1 varchar(50),
Col2 varchar(50)
)
Declare @Out varchar(100),@Query varchar(100)=''

insert into @table
select '100', '*10+2'

select @Out= Col1 + '' + Col2 
from @table
SET @Query = 'SELECT ' +@Out
EXEC (@Query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EXEC SQL query:

```
Declare @table table
(
  Col1 varchar(50),
  Col2 varchar(50)
)
DECLARE @Cal VARCHAR(100)

insert into @table
select '100' , '*10+2'

SELECT @Cal = Col1+''+Col2 from @table
SELECT @Cal = 'SELECT (' + @Cal + ')'
EXEC (@Cal)
```