# Sql Convert string value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to convert string value to floating such as

```
User entered value      Expected Result
1/2                     0.5
1                       1
1/4                     0.25
1 1/2                   1.5
```

How to convert this kind of value in sql server?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: I'm just curious what is the motivation of doing this...and with sql.

Comment: You could make a function on the SQL that calculates them if the numbers are calculateable.

Comment: convertion and then order result

Comment: why cant you just have a mapping table where you store all 1/2=05 and 1/4=0.25 etc and just replace with these values in your table whereever you find these strings like 1/2,1/4 etc

Comment: @Kaushik Halvadia last entry 1+1/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not beautifully, but works

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', val) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(val, 0, CHARINDEX('/', val)) 
                 ELSE val END AS float) /
       CAST(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', val) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('/', val) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(val)))
                 ELSE 1 END AS float)
FROM dbo.test12
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', val) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(val, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', val)) AS float) +
       CAST(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX(' ', val), CHARINDEX('/', val) - CHARINDEX(' ', val)) AS float) /
       CAST(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('/', val) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(val))) AS float)
FROM dbo.test12
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', val) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

This sort of thing is best done in your GUI: evaluate the expression before putting it into the database, not afterwards. If you want to keep the original user input, you can always have your GUI insert that too. Evaluating random user input is dangerous in any system, so it would be best to parse and/or evaluate the input outside the database, both to limit the potential impact and also to use a more powerful (or less specialized, if you prefer) programming language than TSQL.

Having said all that, you can do something with dynamic SQL (assuming that your input is always in the formats that you've shown):

```
declare @input varchar(10)
set @input = '1 1/2'
set @input = replace(@input, ' ', '+')
exec('select cast(' + @input + '.0 as float)')
```

But that has all the issues [of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), including trusting user input. And you can't use dynamic SQL in a TSQL function, so you can't wrap it up conveniently for use in a query. You could use a cursor in a TSQL procedure or write a CLR function or stored procedure, of course, but this sort of task just feels out of place in a database. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722782/storing-formula-equations-in-database-to-be-evaluated-later-sql-server-2005) is very similar, by the way.