# Execute column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do an arithmetic operation to the values saved in SQL table, for example, I have value as 5*10  in next column I want 15

```
EQUATION    VALUE
2+5          7
6+8          14
```

Based on the equation I need to calculate the value.

Comment: So you need to implement a calculator?

Comment: What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing formula (equations) in database to be evaluated later (SQL Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722782/storing-formula-equations-in-database-to-be-evaluated-later-sql-server-2005) Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225143/expression-evaluation-in-sql-stored-procedure  I wouldn't do this in SQL though. `C#` or some other language would be preferable. [This, for instance, is interesting](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Eval-%7C-Dynamically-evaluate-arithmetic-operation-and-expression-in-SQL).

Comment: Also, generally this is done with an `Eval` function would help for google searches around this topic. Like `Eval SQL Server Arithmetic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know by now, SQL Server does not have an EVAL() function. However, with a little dynamic SQL, it is possible, **but really not recommended**.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,[EQUATION] varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2+5')
,(2,'6+8')
,(3,'datediff(DAY,''2018-01-01'',getdate())')  -- Added Just for Fun


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + concat('(',ID,',',[EQUATION],')')
                                     From @YourTable  A
                                     For XML Path (''))
                                 ,1,1,'')
Exec('Select * from (values ' + @SQL + ')A([ID],[Value])')
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value
1   7
2   14
3   189
```

Comment: solved, but concat function is not available  in available in sql server so made minor change

Select ',' +'(' +  CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ','+ [EQUATION] + ')'  From TMPTABLE A

Comment: @GirishA Happy you were able to make the adjustment ... Just assumed 2012+.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the operation as a `SELECT` statement

```
declare @col1 nvarchar(50) = '10+5'

DECLARE @STATEMENT NVARCHAR(50) = 'SELECT'
DECLARE @COMMAND NVARCHAR(50) = @STATEMENT + ' ' + @COL1

exec sp_executesql @COMMAND
```

Output:

> 15