# Storing operators with operands in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I work at a company that sells many versions of a product to several different resellers, and each reseller adds parameters that change the resale price of the product.

For example, we sell a vehicle service contract where, for a certain vehicle, the reserve price of the contract is $36. The dealer marks up every reserve by 30% (to $47), adds a premium of $33 to the reserve price (now $80), and adds a set of fee--like commissions and administrative costs--to bring the contract total to $235.

The reserve price is the same for every dealer on this program, but they all use different increases that are either flat or a percentage. There are of course dozens of parameters for each contract.

**My question is this**: can I store a table of parameters like "x*1.3" or "y+33" that are indexed to a unique ID, and then join or cross apply that table to one full of values like the reserve price mentioned above?

I looked at the SQL Server "table valued parameters," but I don't see from the MSDN examples if they apply to my case.

Thanks so much for your kind replies.

**EDIT:**
As I feared, my example seems to be a little too esoteric (my fault). So consider this:
Twinings recommends different temperatures for brewing various kinds of tea. Depending on your elevation, your boiling point might be different. So there must be a way to store a table of values that looks like this--
[image]
<sub>(source: [twinings.co.uk](https://www.twinings.co.uk/app_/responsive/TwiningsUKI/media/content/About%20Twinings/Latest%20News%20and%20Articles/2016/How-To-Make-The-Perfect-Cup-of-Tea/brewing-tea.jpg?w=500))</sub>

A user enters a ZIP code that has a corresponding elevation, and SQL Server calculates and returns the correct brew temperature for you. Is that any better an example?

Again, thanks to those who have already contributed.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking but I think you are asking if you can store a formula and have your queries execute that formula? You can, but it is usually not a good approach. It requires dynamic for every single query to execute the formula.

Comment: If you mean can you store a string that represents the formula/expression to calculate *x* and have SQL Server interpret the string to calculate the value of *x*, then the answer, in short, is no. You definitely would not be able to index such a thing as **every** value would need to be calculated dynamically..

Comment: Doable, but not suggested.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247851/execute-column-values-in-sql-server/51248368#51248368

Comment: That looks dangerously open to injection @JohnCappelletti (I assume one of the reasons why it is really not recommended).

Comment: @Larnu Thus the caveat.   That said, not all dynamic SQL is open to the wild.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Correct, this all happens behind the scenes. Basically the user has access to a button that spits out a calculated value and all the calculations happen behind the scenes. I'm just looking for a way to wrap all those manipulations up in a single table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I *like* this solution, but it does seem to at least work. The only real way to iteratively construct totals is to use some form of "loop", and the most set-based way of doing that these days is with a recursive CTE:

```
declare @actions table (ID int identity(1,1) not null, ApplicationOrder int not null, 
                        Multiply decimal(12,4), AddValue decimal(12,4))
insert into @actions (ApplicationOrder,Multiply,AddValue) values
(1,1.3,null),
(2,null,33),
(3,null,155)

declare @todo table (ID int not null, Reserve decimal(12,4))
insert into @todo(ID,Reserve) values (1,36)

;With Applied as (
    select
        t.ID, Reserve  as Computed, 0 as ApplicationOrder
    from
        @todo t
    union all
    select a.ID,
      CONVERT(decimal(12,4),
        ((a.Computed * COALESCE(Multiply,1)) + COALESCE(AddValue,0))),
      act.ApplicationOrder
    from
        Applied a
            inner join
        @actions act
            on
                a.ApplicationOrder  = act.ApplicationOrder - 1
), IdentifyFinal as (
    select
        *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ApplicationOrder desc) as rn
    from Applied
)
select
    *
from
    IdentifyFinal
where
    rn = 1
```

Here I've got a simple single set of actions to apply to each price (in `@actions`) and a set of prices to apply them to (in `@todo`). I then use the recursive CTE to apply each action in turn.

My result:

```
ID          Computed                                ApplicationOrder rn
----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------- --------------------
1           234.8000                                3                1
```

Which isn't far off your $235 :-)

I appreciate that you may have different actions to apply to each particular price, and so my `@actions` may instead, for you, be something that works out which rules to apply in each case. That may be one of more CTEs before mine that do that work, possibly using another `ROW_NUMBER()` expression to work out the correct `ApplicationOrder` values. You may also need more columns and join conditions in the CTE to satisfy this.

Note that I've modelled the actions so that each can apply a multiplication and/or an add at each stage. You may want to play around with that sort of idea (or e.g. add a "rounding" flag of some kind as well so that we might well end up with the $235 value).

`Applied` ends up containing the initial values and each intermediate value as well. The `IdentifyFinal` CTE gets us just the final results, but you may want to select from `Applied` instead just to see how it worked.

Comment: Ahh, yes...like in cases where you multiply a value as opposed to add, you have a column that adds zero; in cases where you add a premium you multiply by one and add whatever.  I know that in a view, I would be able to perform operations on a column value, but can I dynamically create a view with a set of stored parameters?

Comment: also your math is perfect, I omitted all the steps in which the values were rounded up or down at various points. I didn't design the system, I just work here man ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple structure to store costs:

```
DECLARE @costs TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Perc DECIMAL(18, 6),
    Flat DECIMAL(18, 6)
);
```

The `Perc` column represents percentage of base price. It is possible to store complex calculations in this structure **but it gets ugly**. For example if we have:

1. Base Price: $100
2. Flat Fee: $20
3. Tax: 11.5%
4. Processing Fee: 3%

Then it will be stored as:

```
INSERT INTO @costs VALUES
-- op example
(1, 0.0,  NULL),
(1, 0.3,  NULL),
(1, NULL, 33.0),
(1, NULL, 155.0),
-- above example
(2, 0.0,          NULL),
(2, NULL,         20.0),
(2, 0.115,        NULL),
(2, NULL,         20.0 * 0.115),
(2, 0.03,         NULL),
(2, NULL,         20.0 * 0.03),
(2, 0.115 * 0.03, NULL),
(2, NULL,         20 * 0.115 * 0.03);
```

And queried as:

```
DECLARE @tests TABLE (
    ID INT,
    BasePrice DECIMAL(18, 2)
);
INSERT INTO @tests VALUES
(1, 36.0),
(2, 100.0);

SELECT t.ID, SUM(
    BasePrice * COALESCE(Perc, 0) + 
    COALESCE(Flat, 0)
) AS TotalPrice
FROM @tests t
INNER JOIN @costs c ON t.ID = c.ID
GROUP BY t.ID
```

```
ID | TotalPrice
---+-------------
1  | 234.80000000
2  | 137.81400000
```

The other, better, solution is to use a structure such as follows:

```
DECLARE @costs TABLE (
    ID INT,
    CalcOrder INT,
    PercOfBase DECIMAL(18, 6),
    PercOfPrev DECIMAL(18, 6),
    FlatAmount DECIMAL(18, 6)
);
```

Where `CalcOrder` represents the order in which calculation is done (e.g. tax before processing fee). `PercOfBase` and `PercOfPrev` specify whether base price or running total is multiplied. This allows you to handle situations where, for example, a commission is added on base price but it must not be included in tax and vice-versa. This approach requires recursive or iterative query.