# parameterize a stored procedure by a simple mathematical expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, expression

I have a bunch of simple expressions, such as:

```
c=a+b
c=a*b
...
```

I would like to pass them as parameter to a stored procedure, which is going to perform an update using them.

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    a int,
    b int,
    c int
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6);

CREATE PROCEDURE sp @left_member varchar(50), @right_member
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET @left_member = @right_member
END

EXEC sp  'c', 'a+b'
EXEC sp  'c', 'a*b'
```

Is there a way of doing something like that ? I would like to possibly avoid dynamic SQL. In my target design, the expressions will be stored in their own table (editable online).

Comment: What you describe sounds like the very definition of dynamic SQL...

Comment: As you know by now, SQL Server does not have an Eval() function.  That said, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247851/execute-column-values-in-sql-server/51248368#51248368

Comment: If you don't want to write Dynamic SQL, then you could use CASE statements, but you need to know all the cases.

Comment: Can you pass a function as parameter to a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally don't recommend doing this, but dynamic SQL is pretty much the solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_exec_dangerous_update (
    @left_member nvarchar(50),
    @right_member nvarchar(50)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'
UPDATE t
    SET [left_member] = [right_member]
';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql, '[left_member]', @left_member), '[right_member]', @right_member);

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Although such code can be useful in a thoughtful, well-designed system, in general it is not needed:

- It exposes the system to SQL injection attacks.  Running "generic" code is just dangerous.
- It does not handle errors, which are easy to occur with this method.

Comment: Would it be recommended to do it in #NET then ? Using Eval() function ?

Comment: Or would it be recommended to call a python script from SQL to perform this instead ?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 using sp_execute_external_script (SQL Server Machine Learning) to run a python script in the context of the database ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . I don't really recommend doing this type of manipulation unless you really know what you are doing.  There are some circumstances where it can be important, but this is not some that is needed for "typical" applications.

Comment: The security issue is language independant ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . Yes.  It is a question of passing user-input as a SQL string.  Validating such input is quite tricky.  I have used SQL generation for some applications.  In such cases, the code is internal to the application -- although a malicious user could still update values in tables that generate the code.